# Pass integer 2D array from java client to python server

Tags: java, python, arrays, sockets

I am trying to pass integer array from Java client to Python server using sockets. I tried to pass the array using Java's `ObjectOutputStream` and get the response. But Python server logs the response as then following;

```
Connected by ('192.168.1.2', 55258)
b'\xac\xed\x00\x05'
b'ur\x00\x02[IM\xba`&v\xea\xb2\xa5\x02\x00\x00'
b'xp\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\....
```

Are these `\x01\x00\` memory locations? How can I fix this issue?

Server (Python):

```
   HOST = 'localhost'
    PORT = 1234
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
        s.bind((HOST, PORT))
        s.listen()
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        with conn:
            print('Connected by', addr)
            while True:
                data = conn.recv(1024)
                if data:
                    print(data)
                else:
                    break
            s.close()
```

Client (Java):

```
        //Variabels
        static Socket s;
        static DataOutputStream dos;
        static PrintWriter pw;


        int [] input_row_data = {1, 60, 402, 8, 2, 2};
            try
            {
                s = new Socket("localhost",1234);
                pw = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
                ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
                out.writeObject(input_row_data);
                pw.flush();
                pw.close();
                s.close();
            }catch(IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: Java's `ObjectOutputStream` uses a Java-specific serialization protocol that won't be understood by python. You need to use a language-independent serialization format. Using JSON as a basis for such a format would probably minimize the amount of code you have to write on each side.

Comment: Does the python part want to see numbers in text form, or does it want to see the numbers in a binary form? Text is easier.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Thank you! Will go with a language-independent serialization format :D

Comment: @NomadMaker Python part want to get the int array as it is, Thats the problem

Comment: No, it doesnt want it as it is, it wants something else. The ObjectOutputStream is only to communicate with other Java code using an ObjectInputStream. My suggestion is to send the array as a series of numbers, either in binary or text. Text has the advantage that you can debug the network communication with telnet.

Comment: The \x characters you see are hex bytes of information.

Comment: @NomadMaker Thats also a great idea! BTW I was able to sort this out using JSONs